# OpenSSL undefined symbol: EVP_mdc2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

I have the following problem with OpenSSL

I did the following:

1. `$ sudo wget "https://ftp.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz"`
2. `$ tar xzf openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz`
3. From the unpacked archieve folder I did `./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.1.1d --openssldir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1d`
4. `$ sudo make`
5. `$ sudo make install`

The installation process didn't return any errors, however if I try

```
/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/bin/openssl version
```

I get the following error:

```
/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/bin/openssl: symbol lookup error: /opt/openssl-1.1.1d/bin/openssl: undefined symbol: EVP_mdc2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2

I also tried `sudo ldconfig` as suggested [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11856) but it didn't do anything.

Please clue me in what's wrong

Comment: Because the old version is only believed to be compatible with a custom engine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/bin/openssl version
```

Comment: It did.. Thanks! The problem was that I have 2 different openSSL installed?